# Change <style> after jQuery scripts

Tags: jquery, css, styles

I load up a site, used a jQuery script to grab the background color of the header when the page is loaded (cued by `$(document).ready(function(global)`), and want to input this value into the background style property of a table.

The table's properties are currently defined using `<style>` / `</style>` tags and it runs before the script can get the desired values. Thus, the color variable that is stored cannot be input into the `<style>` tags, because the `<script>` are run after the `<style>` tags are run.

The question is how do I get a portion of the code to run `<style>` tags after a `<script>` has run so that I can input the stored variable into the tags.

This seems a little backward I know, but the application I'm working on has very strict parameters and the color variable must be defined after loading. Backend coding of the colors is not possible due to the fact that they are stored in temporary cache files, so I am restricted to the situation I've described.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use jQuery to **change** the stylesheet, you use it to interact with the DOM in the same way a stylesheet would.

You make the changes to the styling using the **[`.style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)**.

The following example shows changing the background with `.backgroundColor`:

```js
var headerColour = document.getElementById('header').style.backgroundColor;
var element = document.getElementById('element');
element.style.backgroundColor = headerColour;
```

```css
#element {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" style="background-color: green"></div>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Note that the CSS says the square should be red, but the JavaScript says the square should be green. It becomes green as a result. Styling done via JavaScript will **automatically** be applied after styling applied through CSS (as is seen above).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I don't change the style with the jquery, I define a global attribute with the jquery because I need to grab the header color. Then I need to use that global variable to define the background color of a table, and I need this to be done before the page loads so that the colors don't flicker as the script is run.

Comment: You do a very similar thing; you store the colour of the header as a variable, and the use `.style` to set the table colour's value to that variable. I've update my answer to showcase exactly that.

Comment: ok I figured out how to use the .style  the issue now is getting the jquery script to run before the page is displayed as the table appears white then changes color very quickly but still does not look professional. This can't be done in the html <body> tag because I don't have access to the body tag

Comment: You **always** have access to the body tag; it is always present. Simply modify the CSS itself if you want it to display instantaneously. JavaScript will **always** load after CSS; there is no way to get it to run first.

Comment: But I was sneaky and hid the body until the JS ran. Works like a charm.